# Submit specific input value content with form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement a time clock system where user chooses a week from a dropdown and then gets shown a list of all the days of that week - if they are meant to be working on a day it shows in green and if not it shows in red. User then picks a date, enters time and submits form.

Initially I used two dropdowns but as I cannot reliably style the option in the dropdown I then changed to use AJAX to display the dates as a list. My problem is I need to be able to pass the chosen date which the user clicks on with the form.

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    print_r($_REQUEST);
}  
?>

<form name="form1" id="form1">
    <select name="week" id="week">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="2015-01-12">2015-01-12</option>
        <option value="2015-01-05">2015-01-05</option>
    </select>

    <div id="output"></div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#week").change(function(){
            var wb = $("#week").val();
            var e = 4387;
            var c = 1;
            $.ajax({
                url  : 'get.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data : { wb : wb, e : e, c : c},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#output').html(data);
               }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The AJAX returns the dates and I get an output like below - each date has a input type hidden with its value so it should get submitted with the form:

```
2015-01-12 | 2015-01-13 | 2015-01-14 | 2015-01-15 | 2015-01-16 | 2015-01-17 | 2015-01-18

<input type="hidden" name="date" value="2015-01-12"><span style="color:green">2015-01-12</span> | 
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="2015-01-13"><span style="color:green">2015-01-13</span> | 
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="2015-01-14"><span style="color:green">2015-01-14</span> | 
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="2015-01-15"><span style="color:green">2015-01-15</span> | 
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="2015-01-16"><span style="color:green">2015-01-16</span> | 
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="2015-01-17"><span style="color:red">2015-01-17</span> | 
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="2015-01-18"><span style="color:red">2015-01-18</span>
```

However, when I submit my form I am just getting:

```
Array ( [week] => 2015-01-12 [submit] => Submit )
```

and the chosen date is missing - why are the hidden fields not being submitted and how can I pass just the date clicked to the form so it gets submitted with the other form data?

Comment: Lets see the html returned from the ajax request.

Comment: Am I missing something? You dont have any HIDDEN fields inside the `<form>...</form>`. Also you are getting the SELECTED date passed in `[week] => 2015-01-12`

Comment: Try changing the `name="date"` to `name="date[]"` then you should get an array called `date` returned with the submitted data.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - that returns them all which is definitely progress but I only want to allow user to click one date and then return that one date so the $_POST contains the week and one date rather than the week and 7 dates

Comment: How would you know which one day was chosen?